# Can I hardcode glyph indices in my code?

Tags: windows, winapi, unicode, opentype

Given that the Windows API function `GetGlyphIndices()` can translate a 2 byte UNICODE char code into a glyph index, I intend to hardcode those glyph indices, instead of the UNICODE points. Is that possible ?

I understand that MS could later change the value returned by this function for one particular UNICODE point, but it's my expectation that the current glyph index will be maintained in the glyph set, in that situation.

In other words, my understanding is that if MS decides to associate a new glyph index with a UNICODE point, it will enlarge the glyph set keeping the old glyphs.

Could someone confirm this ?

Comment: These kind of expectations are what keeps programmers busy maintaining their code.  And guys like Raymond busy battling appcompat.  One obvious failure mode that jumps to mind here is the font mapper producing a substitute font because the one you hope to use isn't available on the machine.

Comment: @HansPassant Any program that uses an OpenType font has to access some of the tables in the OpenType font file, like GSUB, GPOS, cmap, etc... It's not just a matter of calling `CreateFont()` or `CreateFontIndirect()`. So the chances are almost null, of a code like this not being able to catch an error originated from a substitute font.

Comment: You might want to make it more obvious in your question that you are talking about OpenType.  While Microsoft has a pretty hard commitment to appcompat, such is not necessarily the case for other OpenType vendors.

Comment: Are you having a problem calling `GetGlyphIndices`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Not at all. My question has to do with the persistence of a glyph in the glyph set of an OpenType font. My belief is that it is persistent, although apparently nothing is said in MSDN, in favor, or against, this assumption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no guarantee that new glyphs will always be appended. (And what if a glyph gets deleted?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have reasons to assume that a glyph doesn't get deleted from the glyph set. For instance, the glyphs 0x01B9, 0x01BD, 0x01C2 and 0x01CE, which are glyph variants of the circunflex, caron, breve and tilde accents, have been superseded by the glyphs 0x1218, 0x1219, 0x121D and 0x121A, in the Cambria Math font, but the old glyphs are still present in the glyph set.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the assumption you make will be valid in the future. Proceed at your own risk, and make sure your customers understand the risk.

Comment: I understand your concern, which is mine also. That's why I posted the question. But I'd like to see what you've just said, in a MSDN doc. Do you know of any reference supporting this ?

Comment: How do you prove a negative? If you cannot find a guarantee, then there is no guarantee.

Comment: I believe the glyphs in a OpenType font replicate the same property, as stated here http://unicode.org/policies/stability_policy.html : Once a character is encoded, it will not be moved or removed.

This policy ensures that implementers can always depend on each version of the Unicode Standard being a superset of the previous version. The Unicode Standard may deprecate the character (that is, formally discourage its use), but it will not reallocate, remove, or reassign the character.

Comment: @user1042389: Where you said glyphs have been supersceded gives a very good reason why you shouldn't cache the glyph index. The index for a given code point can change, leaving your app displaying garbage/incorrect data.

Comment: What @Deanna said. Your example actually proves that glyph indices are unstable.

Comment: @user1042389: you refer to the Unicode stability policy. Unicode is an encoding standard. It does not ensure the stability of font file content. As Raymond has pointed out, there is no guarantee that the font file you're using today won't have its glyphs rearranged or removed at some point in the future. Hard-coding glyphIDs in your code is a great idea if you want to guarantee future bugs and hard-to-maintain code. Otherwise: don't do it.